# Euclidian Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ whose matrix $A$ is a real symmetric matrix.

Could someone show me how to prove that $V=(\text{ker } T) \oplus (\text{Im } T)$ ?

Comment: @egreg Yes I do

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\in \ker T\cap \operatorname{Im}T$. Then $v=Tw$, so
$$
\langle v,v\rangle=
\langle v,Tw\rangle=
\langle Tv,w\rangle=
\langle 0,w\rangle
$$
where $\langle -,-\rangle$ denotes the standard inner product. Therefore…

Comment: Therefore $v=0$. And then I simply use the dimension formula right ?

Comment: I have another question. How can I show that T is an orthogonal projection onto Im(T) if and only if in addition to being symmetric, $A^2=A$

Comment: @user91657 Yes, correct. An operator $T$ is an orthogonal projection if and only if $T^2=T$ and $T$ is self-adjoint.